# useDispatch() Error: Could not find react-redux context value; please ensure the component is wrapped in a <Provider>

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux, react-redux

I am trygin to use React-Redux library and I am getting the error on the title. I wrapped my components with Provider but I still get the error, only if I implement the useDispatch() hook.

The app worked fine, until I added the useDispatch() line. The rest of lines regarding the dispatch function can be removed and I still get the same error.

If you could help me I would really appreciate it. Thanks

Here is my code:

```
import 'react-native-gesture-handler';
import {NavigationContainer} from '@react-navigation/native';
import Navigator from './navigation/Navigator';

import React, {useEffect, useState, useCallback} from 'react';
import {SafeAreaView, StyleSheet, Text, View} from 'react-native';

import {createStore, combineReducers} from 'redux';
import {Provider, useDispatch} from 'react-redux';
import dataReducer from './store/reducers/dataReducer';
import {CONSTANTS} from './constants/constants';
import {saveInitialData} from './store/actions/dataActions';

const App = () => {
  const [fetched, setFetched] = useState(initialState);

  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  const saveInitialDataHandler = useCallback(data => {
    dispatch(saveInitialData(data));
    callback;
  }, []);

  const rootReducer = combineReducers({
    content: dataReducer,
  });

  const store = createStore(rootReducer);

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchData();
  }, []);

  const fetchData = () => {
    fetch(CONSTANTS.database)
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(responseJSON => {
        setFetched(true);
        saveInitialDataHandler(responseJSON);
      });
  };

  if (!fetched) {
    return (
      <Provider store={store}>
        <View stlye={{flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center'}}>
          <Text></Text>
        </View>
      </Provider>
    );
  } else {
    return (
      <Provider store={store}>
        <NavigationContainer>
          <SafeAreaView style={styles.SafeAreaView}>
            <Navigator></Navigator>
          </SafeAreaView>
        </NavigationContainer>
      </Provider>
    );
  }
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  SafeAreaView: {flex: 1},
});

export default App;
```

Answer (score 137, accepted):

`App` must be wrapped in provider since you are using `useDispatch` in it. Right now it's just a child. `Provider` sets the context so only its children can have access to it, not a parent.

One solution would be to create a wrapper component for it:

```js
const AppWrapper = () => {
  const store = createStore(rootReducer);

  return (
    <Provider store={store}> // Set context
      <App /> // Now App has access to context
    </Provider>
  )
}

const App = () => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch(); // Works!
...
```

Comment: Thank you, it worked. For anyone using it, also remember to export your AppWrapper, instead of your App!

Comment: Basically make sure to wrap your App component with the Provider not index.js file which mounts the App component to the DOM.

Comment: Hello, I am having this same issue and when I try this method I receive "ReferenceError: Can't find variable: rootReducer"

Comment: `rootReducer` is the name the OP gave to their combined reducers, yours may be different depending on how you've set up your reducers and imported them.

Answer (score 29):

If you get this error when run `npm run test` Then issues is related your test file.

Update or replace your `app.test.tsx` by below code

NB: Don't forget to install `redux-mock-store` if you don't have already.

```
import React from 'react';
import { render } from '@testing-library/react';

import App from './App';

import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import configureStore from 'redux-mock-store';

describe('With React Testing Library', () => {
    const initialState = { output: 10 };
    const mockStore = configureStore();
    let store;

    it('Shows "Hello world!"', () => {
        store = mockStore(initialState);
        const { getByText } = render(
            <Provider store={store}>
                <App />
            </Provider>
        );

        expect(getByText('Hello World!')).not.toBeNull();
    });
});
```

I got this solution after searching 1 hours.
Thanks a lot to [OSTE](https://github.com/oste)

Original Solution: [Github issues/8145 and solution link](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/8145#issuecomment-515821572)

---

With this solution if you get error like **TypeError: window.matchMedia is not a function** then solve by this way. add those line to your `setupTests.ts` file. Original solution link [stackoverflow.com/a/64872224/5404861](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64872224/5404861)

```
global.matchMedia = global.matchMedia || function () {
  return {
    addListener: jest.fn(),
    removeListener: jest.fn(),
  };
};
```

Answer (score 27):

maybe you imported Provider into the App.js file. Provider needs to be imported into the file index.js.

```
/*index.js*/
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { store } from './store/reduxStore';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import reportWebVitals from './reportWebVitals';

ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <Provider store={store}>
      <App />
    </Provider>
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Answer (score 7):

I did this on the same index.js file for a react-native app.
This way you avoid having to export and add another file just for giving wrapping the App with the provider.

```
const ReduxProvider = () => {
    return(
        <Provider store={store}>
            <App />
        </Provider>
    )
}

AppRegistry.registerComponent(appName, () => ReduxProvider);
```

Answer (score 4):

You can not call

```
const dispatch = useDispatch()
```

in a component that is not inside the container

```
<Provider store={store}></Provider>
```

**Correct example:**

```
const App = ({ Component, pageProps }: AppPropsWithLayout) => {
  const page = (
    <>
      <Component {...pageProps} />
      <Analytics />
    </>
  )

  if (Component.getLayout) {
    return <Provider store={store}>Component.getLayout(page)</Provider>
  }

  return (
    <Provider store={store}>
      <MainLayout>{page}</MainLayout>
    </Provider>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import store from "../redux/Store";

store?.dispatch(actions.setSocket({ socket }));
```

first save the action. Then use dispatch with that store if the component is not saved in Provider.

Answer (score 0):

Happened to me, when I was calling React component as a function, without using it as virtual dom, Comp was independently called not rendered as child of some element

```
function Comp() {
  const a = useSelector(selectA); // throws error
}
Comp();
```

so in my case solution was to call Comp and a component, not as a function
i.e `<Comp />`

Comment: So. What was the solution?

Comment: the solution is to use one level of indirection - i.e. call the selector within Comp. That's what is the accepted solution as well.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes not specifying a client-rendered component in Next.js, throws this error for redux...

So, add 'use client' before importing any libraries,
in my case, this fixed my issue

Answer (score 0):

In my case issue caused by  `"react-redux": "^7.2.5"` and `"@reduxjs/toolkit": "^1.9.7",` Updating to `"react-redux": "^8.0.2"` solved the issue.