# null is not an object (evaluating 't().store') - React Native Expo

Tags: react-native, react-redux, expo

I'm new to Expo. I want to be able to use Expo through web hopefully but got some problem.

***Aim***

I want to obtain a sample sentence to appear [in red drawn area](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SamZl.png)
according to the user's press on either *indefinite article* button or *definite article* button.
The two sample sentences are chosen among...

```
//SampleSentences.js
const SampleSentencesEnglish = {
    'indefinite': <Text>"A man was looking for you"</Text>,
    'definite': <Text>"The man was looking for you"</Text>,
  }
```

***Problem***
I'm using Redux and
I commented out some lines because whenever I allow `const dispatch = useDispatch();`
or
`const currentArticleType= useSelector(articleSelector)`

it throws error

> null is not an object (evaluating 't().store')

***Solution***

Can it be **because I didn't do some extra steps in library installation except for writing library names** inside package.json? Is there a need for an extra step beside writing there library names with versions?

Please check
https://snack.expo.io/@uygarucar/hazardous-sandwich

---

**Code snippet where I get error**

```
//App.js
...
const App = (props) => {
  
  //const dispatch = useDispatch();
  
  const _adjustIndefinite = () => {
    dispatch(setArticleAC('indefinite'));
  };

  const _adjustDefinite = () => {
    dispatch(setArticleAC('definite'));
  };

  //const currentArticleType= useSelector(articleSelector)


  
  return (
    <Provider store={store}>
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={_adjustIndefinite}>
          <Text>indefinite article</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={_adjustDefinite}>
          <Text>definite article</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
        <Text> </Text>
        <Text>Sample Sentence</Text>
        {/*<Text>{sampleSentencesEnglish[currentArticleType]}</Text>*/}
      </View>  
    </Provider>
  );
};

...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I switched from Expo to React Native CLI (I guess it is called so) a more understandable message appeared.

> Could not find react-redux context value; please ensure the component
> is wrapped in a <Provider>

According to this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60329421/usedispatch-error-could-not-find-react-redux-context-value-please-ensure-the), the component, in which useDispatch used, should have  been wrapped by a provider.

Changing from above case to this solved my problem.

```
<Provider store={store}>
  <MainApp/>
</Provider>
```

Watch out that, component that we use useDispatch in is this time inside Provider (MainApp is where we use useDispatch).

Working sample:
https://snack.expo.io/@uygarucar/9b9e72