# dispatch is not a function in react for a simple counter app

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to understand the react context and reducer hooks and coding a simple counter app. In this app, I need three functionality: increment, decrement, and reset.

But when I click the buttons for those functionalities, the console shows the error 'dispatch is not a function'. Also, the counter variable from the context doesn't show any value in the browser where it should show the initial value of 0 because that's what I set it to be.

Here's the code for the app:

`App.js`

```
import { useEffect } from "react";
import { CounterProvider } from "./CounterContext";
import { useCounter, useCounterDispatch } from "./CounterContext";

export default function CounterApp() {
  const counter = useCounter();
  const dispatch = useCounterDispatch();

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("counter: ", counter);
    console.log("dispatch: ", dispatch);
  });

  return (
    <CounterProvider>
      <h2>Counter App</h2>
      <div>
        <button
          onClick={() => {
            dispatch({ type: "increment" });
          }}
        >
          increment
        </button>
        <button
          onClick={() => {
            dispatch({ type: "decrement" });
          }}
        >
          decrement
        </button>
        <button
          onClick={() => {
            dispatch({ type: "reset" });
          }}
        >
          reset
        </button>
        <h3>{counter}</h3>
      </div>
    </CounterProvider>
  );
}
```

`CounterContext.js:`

```
import { createContext, useContext, useReducer } from "react";

const CounterContext = createContext(null);
const CounterDispatch = createContext(null);

export function CounterProvider({ children }) {
  const [counter, dispatch] = useReducer(counterReducer, initialCounter);

  return (
    <CounterContext.Provider value={counter}>
      <CounterDispatch.Provider value={dispatch}>
        {children}
      </CounterDispatch.Provider>
    </CounterContext.Provider>
  );
}

export function useCounter() {
  return useContext(CounterContext);
}

export function useCounterDispatch() {
  return useContext(CounterDispatch);
}

function counterReducer(counter, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case "increment": {
      return counter = counter + 1;
    }

    case "decrement": {
      return counter = counter - 1;
    }

    case "reset": {
      return 0;
    }

    default: {
      throw Error("Unknown action: " + action.type);
    }
  }
}

const initialCounter = 0;
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [useDispatch() Error: Could not find react-redux context value; please ensure the component is wrapped in a <Provider>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60329421/usedispatch-error-could-not-find-react-redux-context-value-please-ensure-the)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use the Counter and Dispatch Contexts inside the CounterApp component, because it's not wrapped inside the provider. Your `CounterApp` component renders the provider, so you'll need to create one more component that will consume this context and pass it as a child of `CounterProvider`, for example:

```
import { useEffect } from "react";
import { CounterProvider } from "./CounterContext";
import { useCounter, useCounterDispatch } from "./CounterContext";

export default function CounterApp() {
  return (
    <CounterProvider>
      <CounterAppInner />
    </CounterProvider>
  );
}

function CounterAppInner() {
  const counter = useCounter();
  const dispatch = useCounterDispatch();

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("counter: ", counter);
    console.log("dispatch: ", dispatch);
  });

  return (
    <>
      <h2>Counter App</h2>
      <div>
        <button
          onClick={() => {
            dispatch({ type: "increment" });
          }}
        >
          increment
        </button>
        <button
          onClick={() => {
            dispatch({ type: "decrement" });
          }}
        >
          decrement
        </button>
        <button
          onClick={() => {
            dispatch({ type: "reset" });
          }}
        >
          reset
        </button>
        <h3>{counter}</h3>
      </div>
    </>
  )
}
```