# React-redux context not found error when using useSelector hook

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I'm building a React app using Redux for state management. I have set up the Redux store and Provider in my index.js file:

```js
// index.js

import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import store from './store';

ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <App />
  </Provider>  
);
```

In my App component, I try to access the store using the useSelector hook from react-redux:

```js
// App.jsx

import { useSelector } from 'react-redux';

function App() {

  const state = useSelector(state => state); // throws error

  // ...
}
```

However, this throws the following error:

```
Error: Could not find react-redux context value; please ensure the component is wrapped in a <Provider>
```

I have confirmed:

- The store is created and exported properly in store.js
- App is the root component being passed to Provider
- I'm importing useSelector from 'react-redux'

But I'm still seeing this context not found error. What am I missing in the Provider setup to make the Redux store available to components using hooks like useSelector?

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [useDispatch() Error: Could not find react-redux context value; please ensure the component is wrapped in a <Provider>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60329421/usedispatch-error-could-not-find-react-redux-context-value-please-ensure-the)

Comment: I see no overt issue with the specific code snippets you've shared. Can you [edit] to provide a more complete [mcve] enough a reader here could reasonably reproduce the issue you have? Could you also try creating a ***running*** [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/) demo that reproduces the issue we could inspect live?

Answer (score 1):

Try passing context = {null} in provider wrapper as follow

```
<Provider store={store} context = {null}>
<App />


 </Provider>
```